# Unable to read the properties of my React navigation object

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am getting the following error when I try navigate:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')`

Here's my main component:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<StackParamList>();

type StackParamList = {
    Home: undefined;
    NewTrip: undefined;
  };

export default function UserStack() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="NewTrip" component={NewTripsScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Here's where I'm unsuccessfully trying to call it:

```
const TripsProfileScreen: FunctionComponent<TripsSectionProfileProps> = (
  props, navigation
) => {
 
  return (
    <Container>
 <IconButton
            onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('NewTrip')}
          </IconButton>
 </Container>
)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`props` is the object with [route](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop) and [navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop).

```
function Screen({ route, navigation }: Props) {
  // ...
}

const Screen: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({route, navigation}) => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: How would that look with a functional component?

Answer (score 1):

try to add {} on props, it'll look like:

```
const TripsProfileScreen: FunctionComponent<TripsSectionProfileProps> = (
  {props, navigation}
) => {
 
  return (
    <Container>
 <IconButton
            onPress={() =>  navigation.navigate('NewTrip')}
          </IconButton>
 </Container>
)
}
```